# Do I need a loadbalancer in an AWS elastic beanstak environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

My applications run on ElasticBeanstalk and communicate purely with internal services like Kinesis and DynamoDB. There is no web traffic needed? Do I need an ElasticLoadBalancer in order to scale my instances up and down. I want to add and remove instances purely based on some cloudwatch metrics? Do I need the ELB to do managed updates etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no traffic to the service then there is no need to have a load balancer.

In fact the load balancer is primarily to distribute inbound traffic such as web requests.

Autoscaling can still be accomplished without a load balancer with scaling based on the CloudWatch metric that you want to use. In fact this is generally how consumer based applications tend to work.

To create this without a load balancer you would want to configure you environment as a [worker environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html).

Comment: Do the resources like Kinesis and DynamoDB have to be in the same VPC as the elastic beanstalk environment? Also the only costs that I will pay to Amazon is for the nodes that I use in the beanstalk right? Since I am not using a load balancer I won't have to pay for that or any other resources?

Comment: Kinesis and DynamoDB do not live in a VPC, your application can use them from any region but generally it is advised to use everything as geographically close as you can. You only pay for what you use, this won’t create a load balancer so you will not pay for it :)

Answer (score 0):

@Chris already anwsered, but I would like to complement his answer for the following:

> There is no web traffic needed?

Even if you communicate with  Kinesis and DynamoDB only, your instances still need to be able to access internet to **communicate with the AWS services**. So the web traffic is required from your instances. The direct inbound traffic to your instances is not needed.

To fully separate your EB env from the internet you should have a look at the following:

- [Using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html)

The document describes what you can do and want can't be done when using **private subnets**.

Comment: Yes all my resources are completely inside my Amazon AWS account. My Elastic beanstalk env will be within it's own VPC and my resources will be in the default VPC of my AWS account.

Comment: @CodeJunkie Hi, You you have EB in one VPC and some other resources in other VPC (default one), the first one need either internet connection to connect to resources in the second one, or you need to establish peering connection between the two. EB will still require internet connection anyway for some of its operations.